# maxmind GeoLite2-City accuracy_radius

Tags: maxmind

I am using the MaxMind GeoLite2-City data to locate IP addresses. I am finding that I only ever see 3 distinct values for the location/accuracy_radius field in a response - 1, 100 and 937 with the most frequent result being 937

eg - on a debian box I am seeing:

`/usr/bin/mmdblookup --file /usr/local/maxminddb/GeoLite2-City.mmdb --ip=52.84.206.231 location accuracy_radius
  937`

Am I correct in interpreting this as a radius of uncertainty of 937 Kilometres?

If correct then I am afraid I have to ignore the uncertainty and just use the (usually quite sensible looking) location data that is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

The accuracy radius creates a circle around the coordinates in which the actual location of the device likely falls. It is measured in kilometers. If you look at the CSV version of the database, you will see that many other values are also returned. A radius of 937 km likely indicates only country-level knowledge about the location of the IP address.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The results are then somewhat surprising. If there is only country-level knowledge, then is it not misleading to return all the other attributes associated with the IP address, such as City, Postal code etc?